# How do I turn this into a Setter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

```
setOwner :: File -> User -> File
setOwner f o = f & ownerID .~ (o ^. User.uid)
```

How do I turn this into a `Setter`?

I can't make it a lens because `getUser :: UserID -> IO User` is an impure function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my previous answer was wrong. Whoops!

Here you go:

```
ownerS :: Setter File File () User
ownerS = sets (\f file -> setOwner file (f ()))
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. I was confused how this could be an uncommon problem with lenses.